# Trying to block images from google image indexing but not working

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, nginx, google-image-search

I am trying to block images from google image search, but for some reason they are not working. I have a Wordpress self-hosted blog and I have full access to the backend. HTML of `mydomain.com` looks like below:

```
<a href="mydomain.com/image.png" data-id="4989" rel="nofollow" aria-label="open this media" data-type="image" class="fg-thumb">
  <span class="fg-image-wrap">
    <img width="288" height="384" class="skip-lazy fg-image" role="presentation" data-src-fg="mydomain.com/image_thumbnail.png" src="mydomain.com/image_thumbnail.png" loading="eager">
  </span>
</a>
```

Google image search using the query `site:mydomain.com` shows both `mydomain.com/image.png` and `mydomain.com/image_thumbnail.png` pointing to `mydomain.com`. I am trying to remove these image entries from showing up on image search results.

I am aware of Google Search Console removal and it is not a solution I am looking for.

On my NGINX backend, the `png` files are being served with the header `x-robots-tag: noindex`. Image files are not being blocked by `robots.txt` so that the crawlers can see the  header, which I think is how it should be done.

So far the above implementation is not working in preventing the images from showing up on Google image search. I have almost ruled out cache issues, because `mydomain.com` renders dynamically showing random images and new images keep popping up on image search. (**UPDATE:** It looks like there is a cache issue. I am not using any CDN. After updating `mydomain.com` to use only a few images, images that are not used still pop up in google image search.)

The page `mydomain.com` does not have `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`, and should not have it because `mydomain.com` needs to be indexed.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It takes Google bot a while to recrawl URLs, and then a while to update the index. I think the solution is to use the removal tool to temporarily remove the images (by URLs of the images, rather than the pages containing them), to cover the period of time until Google recrawls them. It might be a good idea to submit an up-to-date sitemap.xml with higher priority to pages with images to help Google crawl everything more efficiently.

Comment: Do you have links to these images on your website pages ?

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes. The main page has two links in total but they point to random images, dynamically generated each time the page loads. The links are generated with `rel="nofollow"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. The gallery plugin I was using (Foogallery) was also rendering a javascript portion for pagination. Switching the gallery option to render pagination in HTML resolved this. It looks like Googlebot may have been reading image links from the javascript portion.

Answer (score 0):

Google recommends two ways to achieve this goal:

1. Robots.txt declaration:

   Disallow: /image.png
2. X-Robots-Tag HTTP header

I would recommend you the X-Robots-Tag HTTP header as the most effective solution.

More information here: [Remove images hosted on your site from search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/prevent-images-on-your-page)

Comment: The asker states that they are intentionally not using `robots.txt` to block images, and states that they are already using the X-Robots-Tag HTTP header but it is not working.

Comment: I am aware of this method but this does not work for some reason.